# How migration from learnpress to moodle

Tags: moodle, learnpress

How can I migrate platform learnpress/wordpress  contains courses pdf and video to moodle ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think unfortunately this question is too vague to be answered here. How many courses? Are there any blended learning components? Do you want to bring across your existing learners and their learning history? Do you want federated sign in from another system (Microsoft Azure etc.)? Do you have course programmes for different users or groups of users? Do you have any recipes set up that automate progress or signups etc.? Are there any specific features in Moodle that you're wanting to take advantage of? Will any of your business processes change?

Your best bet would be to contact a reputable Moodle specialist and they can take this further for you with a proper quotation for the work which would involve the necessary discovery process and design of a solution in Moodle that does what you need.